# Npm start doesn't work in an Angular 2 and Laravel 5 project

Tags: package.json, npm-start

I am working on a Laravel 5.2 and Angular 2 project and I've just finished setting up angular but when running `npm start`, I get the following error :

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ postinstall script 'typings install'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Can you guys help me ?

This is the content of my `package.json` :

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch",
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "elixir-typescript": "^1.1.2",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your `package.json`. Looks like `start` script is missing.

Comment: what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: You should add your `package.json` to your question, so we can help you

Comment: I did some changes on my package.json and I still get an error ! have a look, I just edited my question

Comment: Your formatting of question is unreadable. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: As for the the error. Have you read it? it tells you `Failed at the @ postinstall script 'typings install'.` Have you tried googling it?

Comment: I came back to the angular 2 quickstart and I found out that I missed some dependencies : "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4" ! now it works just fine ! thanks to all ov u :D

Comment: @AndreiZhytkevich I am sorry, I dont often ask questions on stack, that's why ! I solved the problem ! thank you :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is failing while trying to run 'typings install'. 
1. Include typings in devDependencies

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

2. Run npm install
3. Create typings.json as below

   ```
   {
     "globalDependencies": {
       "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
       "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
       "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160807145350"
     }
   }
   ```
4. npm start

   > if you still having issue install typings globally 
   >   npm install typings --global

Comment: That's what I did and it worked just fine ! Now I am having another issue :/ when the application is served , I get a message in my browser saying 'cannot GET /' ! I am new to angular , so I couldn't figure it out

Comment: Need more details to understand the actual problem. Can you create plunker

Comment: It's a whole laravel application. I am afraid it would be difficult to create a plunker. Just tell me what details do you need and I'll have you know !

Comment: Then it should be issue with Laravel routing not Angular.

Comment: I turned back to angular 1 ! Im much more familiar with it ! I have no problems now ! Thank you friend :D

Answer (score 0):

I too face this problem i do the following steps

```
 1. i uninstall nodejs and install the latest version.
 2. close the command promt and open.
 3. execute npm install
 4. execute npm build(not nesessery) 
 5. execute npm start
```

This works for me.

Comment: For my case , it was just some missing dependencies in my package.json ! My problem is solved, than u a lot